# How can i force Android to not use certain language files that are within a used library project?

Tags: android, internationalization

I have a library project with several language files, mainly strings. In one app I need to use the library but I want to use only some of the language files (contract reasons).

How can I force Android to disregard the existance of languages when building the app ?

Comment: make a copy of library project and delete files. then again add to your project as a library

Comment: i would have to do that with every change in the library which kinda defeats the purpose of having a library in the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio, add a `resConfigs` line to your `build.gradle` file, to limit the packaging system to only include your desired languages:

```
android {
    // other stuff

    defaultConfig {
        // other stuff
        resConfigs "en", "de", "fr", "es"
    }
}
```

See [Cyril Mottier's "Putting your APKs on a Diet" post](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/) for more.

Comment: I am still using eclipse, anything similar there ?

Comment: @NikkyD: Not that I am aware of.